# Django+Nginx having issue with SSE

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, server-sent-events

I made an API on django rest framework, I have SSE via django-eventstream
Deployed everything on the server (django in docker), wrote a config for nginx
But for some reason the SSE query does not work, everything else works
I even added print to the function from the module to check if the request reaches the api, everything is ok
But in the postman there is an endless sending of the request, although I checked locally - everything worked

Nginx conf

```
location /events/orders/ {
        proxy_pass http://172.23.0.3:8005/events/orders/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";

  proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Content-Type text/event-stream;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_buffers 8 32k;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
}
```

ASGI

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'sushi_api.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

Also there are no errors anywhere